# Keep hover event after click event is triggered Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, jquery-hover

So i am having a little problem.
I have a bunch of div 's all with the same class and i made it so that, when the mouse is on them, they gain a border and when the mouse is off they lose that same border. The thing is i also added a click event to them but once i click on them, they no longer respond wether to the mouseenter/mouseleave events nor the click events. In other words after the first click, all the events are gone.

Here are my div 's

```
<div class="hover-div series-div image-series-div">
            <img class="slide-div-series-image" src="../../Imagens/PBSerie.jpg">
            <b class="slide-font">Serie lel</b>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-div series-div image-series-div">
            <img class="slide-div-series-image" src="../../Imagens/stargateATLSerie.jpg">
            <b class="slide-font">Serie lel</b>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-div series-div image-series-div">
            <img class="slide-div-series-image" src="../../Imagens/stargateATLSerie.jpg">
            <b class="slide-font">Serie lel</b>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-div series-div image-series-div">
            <img class="slide-div-series-image" src="../../Imagens/stargateATLSerie.jpg">
            <b class="slide-font">Serie lel</b>
        </div>
        <div class="hover-div series-div image-series-div">
            <img class="slide-div-series-image" src="../../Imagens/stargateATLSerie.jpg">
            <b class="slide-font">Serie lel</b>
        </div>
```

and here is the Jquery where i handle the events

```
$(".hover-div").on({
  click: function() {
    buildPage($(this).prop("id"));
  }, mouseenter: function() {
    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();
    $(this).css("box-shadow", "0 0 0 2px white inset");
  }, mouseleave: function() {
    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();
    $(this).css("box-shadow", "none");
  }
});
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Ok i now know for sure that the problem relies on the click event. It only triggers once and it kind of disables the other events also?

Comment: Did you try using CSS for the box-shadow when hovering the image? Also, what does your "buildPage()" method do? It seems something inside it is breaking the js.

Comment: Please, share the "buildPage" function code, that function is the one that may be breaking the js

Comment: Echo @Mindastic's comment - What does buildPage do? Whatever it's doing, it's breaking the events. Is it removing the .hover-div class?

Answer (score 0):

After a quick test I think your code is OK as you can simply use a DIFFERENT box-shadow color like this:

```
$(this).css("box-shadow", "0 0 0 2px red inset");
```

You can see a red box on the div hovered.